# Problems with r+ mode in fopen()

Tags: c, file-io

I was trying out the various modes of opening a file in C. I am stuck a little at the modes of r+, w+ and a+.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    .....
    /* make a file with something in it */
    if( (fp = fopen( filename, "w" )) )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "abcd" );
        fclose( fp );
    }
    /* see how r+ works */
    if( (fp = fopen( filename, "r+" )) )
    {
        int c = 0;

        /* read something */
        c = fgetc( fp );
        printf( "c is %c\n", c );

        /* write something */
        fseek( fp, -1, SEEK_CUR );
        fputc( 'x', fp );
        fflush(fp);

        /* read something */
        c = fgetc( fp );
        printf( "c is %c\n", c );

        /* rewind and show the whole thing */
        rewind( fp );
        while( (c = fgetc( fp )) != EOF )
        {
            printf( "c is %c\n", c );
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following output -

c is a

c is b

c is x

c is b

c is c

c is d

Even if I remove the `fflush()` here -

```
/* write something */
fseek( fp, -1, SEEK_CUR );
fputc( 'x', fp );
//fflush(fp);
```

it gives me the same output. So how come I am able to write without `fflush()` on the output stream?(Am I right that `fputc()` writes on the output stream?) Also, can I use `fflush()` instead of `fseek()` in the above code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per C11 7.21.5.3.7:

> When a file is opened with update mode ... output shall not be
>   directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush`
>   function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos` or
>   `rewind`) and input shall not be directly followed by output without
>   an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input
>   operation encounters end-of-file.

The fact that you get the same input without your `fflush()` call is not guaranteed by the standard (although some implementations, including glibc, allow it, so it's not all that surprising to see it work here).

For your other question, no, you can't use `fflush()` instead of `fseek()` here, because your `fseek()` comes before an output operation, not an input operation. `fflush()` is only meaningful for output streams, and for update streams where the most recent operation was not input.

Comment: Thanks! that clarifies a lot. Also, anything that we write (like `fputc()`) happens on the output stream right?

Comment: You've got the right idea, but technically when you open with `r+` you have one update stream here, not separate output and input streams. Functions like `fputc()` will output to the update stream, and functions like `fgetc()` will get input from the update stream.